# Advice for building a website with an embedded blog-like feature

Tags: php, javascript, html

A charity has asked me to revamp their old website.  They don't have much money to spend, but want some sections to be easily updated (e.g. "latest news") with text and photos by non-technical people.

I have experience with JavaBeans, PHP, SQL, AJAX, etc, but web design is not my speciality.  I am looking for any tools (javascript libraries, content management systems, template engines) and techniques that can make my life easier here.

Their current host (ukhost4u) does provide PHP and MySQL support, but I'm not sure if this is sufficient for complex CMS or framework libraries.

Any hints or links to resources much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a free hosted solution, like wordpress.com or blogger.com ? They'd end up with a tool that's pretty usable, they'd have no hosting costs, ...

Comment: They really want something more personalised and using their own domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking your question down a little bit, i'm able to glean that you require:

- Some advice concerning hosting
- A means of developing a site quickly

Concerning the former, there are a number of cheap VPS hosts out there who offer a really good service and pretty much full control over the server you want to manage. [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com) and [Linode](http://www.linode.com) being 2 good examples.

As for speedy development, you might look at building the site using a CMS or development framework. Since you can't invest much in the server owing to budget constraints, you should look at a light framework or CMS. E.g.

CMS

- [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org)
- [Expression Engine](http://expressionengine.com/)

FRAMEWORK

- [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com)
- [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org)

All of which require MySQL, so make sure you do try and get a decent server in this respect.

Another solution would be [Drupal](http://drupal.org) used with a host like [Acquia](http://acquia.com). In itself it is quite heavy but if you use a third party that take care of the hosting it would be quite convenient.

As for design, you can find a number of cheap templates that will sit nicely in the likes of Wordpress and Drupal, which will also cut down some development time.

Comment: Are hosts like linode and slicehost the standard way of hosting a more complex (i.e. php + sql) website?  I always assumed hosts would provide an sql server and web hosting, without going so far as to provide an entire linux virtual server!

Comment: OK, turns out the charity's current host (ukhost4u) already provides php and mysql support (so they were vastly overpaying for their simple html site!), but not a full virtual server.  Would this be sufficient for something like CodeIgniter or Kohana (I noticed, for example, that there are CodeIgniter-specific hosting companies)?

Comment: Oh, and of course, thanks a lot for the links and info, very useful.

Comment: @Dave I don't know much about ukhost4u but I suspect they'd be able to handle Codeigniter or Kohana as both frameworks are very light. Yes, Linode et al. give you a full VPS very cheaply! But obviously you'd have to take some responsibility for managing OS security updates and the initial web server set up.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems) like Drupal or Wordpress. It installs in a pinch and benefits from frequent updates, requiring much less development work.

Comment: How restricted are you in the layout using a CMS, though?  E.g. is the wordpress libary as restrictive as the wordpress website?

Comment: Drupal is quite heavy so warrants extra care in a) choosing a suitable host b) optimizing for performance

Comment: If you install the CMS on your own server, in general you may create your own theme, thus you can tweak virtually anything. It depends on the CMS used though. I have personaly used Dotclear (http://dotclear.org/) whose themes are *totally* customizable, i.e. thanks to a template system you may generate exactly the HTML you want. I believe the same applies to Wordpress.